# Having a issue accessing/loading QJSon dylib at runtime on Mac OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, dylib, qjson

I compiled the QJSon code from the command line and it generated a dylib (libqjson.0.7.1.dylib) I then added this file as an external dependency to one of the libraries in my app. (using Xcode 4.3 as the IDE) everything seems to compile correctly. When i go to run the app i get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/shawneckley/Mac_Dev/Development/build/thirdparty/qjson/src/lib/libqjson.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/shawneckley/Mac_Dev/Development/Build/bin/Debug/libstonewedgeaccountandclient.dylib
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

any idea why this could be happening?